# How to post array by one input angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have below code to post a tags list , when I am typing a list of numbers like 3453453,345345,345345,567567676 in my tags `input` angular posts only one number from the list:

HTML

```
 <tags-input placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
                        min-length="1"
                        max-length="11"
                        ng-class="{'read-input': tags.length > 6}"
                        allowed-tags-pattern="^[0-9]+$" max-tags="6" ng-model="tags"></tags-input>


                <input type="hidden" ng-model="post.phones">
```

Angular code :

```
$scope.$watch('tags', function (tags) {
    if (angular.isArray(tags)) {
        $scope.post.phones = tags.map(function (tags) {
            return parseInt(tags.text, 10);
        });
    } else {
        $scope.post.phones = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: your model must be as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be add model to tags-input resolve your problem.

```
<tags-input
ng-model="post.phones"
placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
min-length="1"
max-length="11"
ng-class="{'read-input': tags.length > 6}"
allowed-tags-pattern="^[0-9]+$"
max-tags="6"></tags-input>
```

Comment: you have used ng-model twice, please fix and answer properly.

Comment: but how to fix the angular code?   `$scope.$watch('tags', function (tags) {
    if (angular.isArray(tags)) {
        $scope.post.phones = tags.map(function (tags) {
            return parseInt(tags.text, 10);
        });
    } else {
        $scope.post.phones = [];
    }
});`

Comment: amirAli I think u don't need to $scope.$watch . after data entry finish in tags-input u could post your data.

Comment: I need this to remove `text : ` from array and array just be a number list

Comment: befor posting form convert string array to number array.

Comment: how do that before posting form?

Comment: similar this : for(var i=0; i<$scope.post.phones.length; i++) { $scope.post.phones[i] = parseInt($scope.post.phones[i], 10); }

Comment: thanks, but i think this code just convert `"23423"` to `23423` and can not remove `"text" : ""`

Comment: please display me tags array .

Comment: tags array : `phones: [{text: "345345"}, {text: "34534535"}, {text: "345342"}, {text: "745674567"}, {text: "125443524"}]`   i want to be `phones :[345345,345354,34535]`

Comment: this function convert :  for(var i=0; i<$scope.phones.length; i++) {
      $scope.phones[i] = parseInt($scope.phones[i].text, 10);
      }

Comment: please if i help u accept my answer and vote up . thanks